# Remove data from Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
var data = [
    {month: 'january', year: '2011', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2011', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2011', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2011', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2011', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2011', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2011', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2011', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2011', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2011', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2012', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2012', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2012', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2012', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2012', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2012', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2012', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2012', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2012', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2012', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2015', val: '5.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2015', val: '10.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2015', val: '2.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2015', val: '52.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2015', val: '17.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2015', val: '5.50', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2015', val: '1.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2015', val: '62.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2016', val: '5.60', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2016', val: '41.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2016', val: '42.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: '43.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2016', val: '12.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2016', val: '21.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2016', val: '46.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2016', val: '12.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2016', val: '12.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2017', val: '5.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2017', val: '12.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2017', val: '10.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '3.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2017', val: '2.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2017', val: '8.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2017', val: '65.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2017', val: '6.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2017', val: '7.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2017', val: '90.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2018', val: '5.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2018', val: '3.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2018', val: '78.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '60.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2018', val: '90.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2018', val: '62.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2018', val: '10.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2018', val: '1.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2018', val: '45.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2018', val: '5.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2013', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2015', val: '85.30', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2015', val: '10.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2016', val: '63.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2016', val: '74.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2016', val: '3.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2016', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2016', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2016', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2016', val: '41.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2016', val: '32.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2016', val: '55.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2017', val: '96.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2017', val: '85.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2017', val: '99.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '99.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2017', val: '98.90', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2017', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2017', val: '74.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2017', val: '62.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2017', val: '51.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2017', val: '41.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2018', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2018', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2018', val: '41.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '15.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2018', val: '3.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2018', val: '14.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2018', val: '52.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2018', val: '12.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2018', val: '10.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2018', val: '11.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},    
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '50.00', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '51.00', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '52.00', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '2.00', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '48.90', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '47.00', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '74.00', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '10.00', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '65.00', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '82.25', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '35.00', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '78.00', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '81.00', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '22.00', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '98.00', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '98.00', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '83.00', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '55.00', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '74.00', area: 'A', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '31.00', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '54.00', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '1.00', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '52.00', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '3.00', area: 'A', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '56.00', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '57.00', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '12.00', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '14.00', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '85.00', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '63.00', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '41.80', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '13.00', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '1.00', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '88.00', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '84.00', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '42.00', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '71.00', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '63.00', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '15.00', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '10.00', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '10.00', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '7.00', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2014', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '9.00', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '86.00', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '11.00', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '9.00', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '8.00', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '10.00', area: 'A', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '6.00', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '98.00', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '6.00', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '83.00', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '40.00', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '6.00', area: 'A', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '7.00', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '47.00', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '8.00', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '70.00', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '3.85', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '8.00', area: 'A', day:'sunday'}
];
```

I can imagine this data in tabular form:

[image]

I want to delete columns that contain all `NaN` values (gray cells) but keeping the common minimum year. For this reason the 2015 column of `Area = B` is not to be deleted because in `Area = A` there are data relating to the year 2015.

So, in this design I want to remove only cells (so data) with red border.

[image]

That is, I would like to get this array of objects:

```
var data = [
    {month: 'january', year: '2015', val: '5.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2015', val: '10.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2015', val: '2.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2015', val: '52.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2015', val: '17.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2015', val: '5.50', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2015', val: '1.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2015', val: '62.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2016', val: '5.60', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2016', val: '41.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2016', val: '42.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: '43.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2016', val: '12.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2016', val: '21.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2016', val: '46.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2016', val: '12.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2016', val: '12.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2017', val: '5.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2017', val: '12.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2017', val: '10.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '3.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2017', val: '2.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2017', val: '8.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2017', val: '65.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2017', val: '6.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2017', val: '7.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2017', val: '90.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2018', val: '5.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2018', val: '3.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2018', val: '78.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '60.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2018', val: '90.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2018', val: '62.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2018', val: '10.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2018', val: '1.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2018', val: '45.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2018', val: '5.00', area: 'A', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2015', val: '85.30', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2015', val: '10.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2015', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2016', val: '63.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2016', val: '74.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2016', val: '3.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2016', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2016', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2016', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2016', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2016', val: '41.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2016', val: '32.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2016', val: '55.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2017', val: '96.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2017', val: '85.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2017', val: '99.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '99.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2017', val: '98.90', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2017', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2017', val: '74.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2017', val: '62.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2017', val: '51.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2017', val: '41.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'january', year: '2018', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'february', year: '2018', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'march', year: '2018', val: '41.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '15.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'may', year: '2018', val: '3.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'june', year: '2018', val: '14.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'july', year: '2018', val: '52.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'august', year: '2018', val: '12.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'september', year: '2018', val: '10.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'october', year: '2018', val: '11.00', area: 'B', day:''},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '50.00', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '51.00', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '52.00', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '2.00', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '48.90', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '47.00', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '74.00', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '10.00', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '65.00', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '82.25', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '35.00', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '78.00', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '81.00', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '22.00', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '98.00', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '98.00', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '83.00', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '55.00', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2017', val: '74.00', area: 'A', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '31.00', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '54.00', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '1.00', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '52.00', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'april', year: '2018', val: '3.00', area: 'A', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '56.00', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '57.00', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '12.00', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '14.00', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '85.00', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '63.00', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '41.80', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '13.00', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '1.00', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: 'NaN', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '88.00', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '84.00', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '42.00', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '5.00', area: 'B', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '71.00', area: 'B', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '63.00', area: 'B', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '15.00', area: 'B', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '10.00', area: 'B', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '10.00', area: 'B', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '7.00', area: 'B', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '9.00', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '86.00', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '11.00', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '9.00', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '8.00', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2016', val: '10.00', area: 'A', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '6.00', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '98.00', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '6.00', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '83.00', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '40.00', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2017', val: '6.00', area: 'A', day:'sunday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '7.00', area: 'A', day:'monday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '47.00', area: 'A', day:'tuesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '8.00', area: 'A', day:'wednesday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: 'NaN', area: 'A', day:'thursday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '70.00', area: 'A', day:'friday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '3.85', area: 'A', day:'saturday'},
    {month: 'december', year: '2018', val: '8.00', area: 'A', day:'sunday'}
];
```

I explain better: I would like to visualize this data and I would use a slider over the years that allows the user to select the year he prefers. The slider is unique and controls the entire `data` object. In this case I would have a slider with range 2015-2018: starting from 2015 because I have data related to 2015-areaA.
It would not make sense to delete the 2015-areaB data column (it has all the NaN values), because the slider starts from 2015, I prefer to leave them even if they are NaN.

How can I do?

*NOTE: I had to remove the data for November and December because StackOverflow does not let me enter more than 30000 characters.*

Comment: Have you written any code in an attempt to accomplish this yourself yet?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Honestly, no. I don't know how to make the proper checks to remove the years with NaN values but keep the common minimum year

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "common minimum year"?

Comment: @joe-tom Of sure. I would like to visualize this data and I would use a slider over the years that allows the user to select the year he prefers. The slider is unique and controls the entire `data` object. In this case I would have a slider with range 2015-2018: starting from 2015 because I have data related to 2015-areaA.
It would not make sense to delete the 2015-areaB data column (it has all the NaN values), because the slider starts from 2015, I prefer to leave them even if they are NaN.
I hope I explained myself.

Comment: Do you want to delete all objects with NaN values except the first per year (or month)?

Answer (score 0):

```
var validYear = false;
for (var month in data) {
    // Get our data for the month
    let monthData = data[month];

    // If value is !NaN (so a valid number) then:
    if (!isNaN(monthData.value)) {
        // Data exists for this year so make sure it isn't deleted
        validYear = true;
    } else {
        // If we are in october and there's been no valid number then delete this year
        if (monthData.month == "october" && validYear == false) {
            // Delete all of this years' data
            for (var deleteIndex = (month - 9); deleteIndex < month; deleteIndex++) {
                delete data[deleteIndex];
            }
        }
    }
    if (monthData.month == "october") {
        // Reset our valid year
        validYear = false;
    }
}
```

That's a rough idea. It may not be perfect but should get you almost there. Your data only goes to October hence the use of that as the key but you can easily swap it for December if that exists in your data.